# What is difference between SDL Tridion Sites and SDL Tridion Docs 13

Tags: sdl-cloud

We are planning to upgrade SDL Web 8.5 to SDL Tridion Sites.
I am looking difference between SDL Tridion Sites and SDL Tridion Docs 13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SDL Tridion Sites 9 will be the successor of SDL Web 8.5, which is a Web Content Management (WCM) solution, but it is not released yet.

SDL Tridion Docs 13, is a DITA-based structured content management solution, which was formerly SDL Knowledge Center.

SDL Tridion Sites and Docs are part of the SDL Tridion DX suite.

You have tagged your question with [sdl-cloud](/questions/tagged/sdl-cloud), so maybe your question is referring to that, but I think it makes sense that you **edit** your question and provide a bit more detail around the why of your question. Why are you planning to upgrade from Web 8.5 to Sites exactly, what is the driver behind this?